# Problem with HtmlHelper and MVC not seeing my new method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to create this HtmlHelper method:

```
namespace Power.WebUx.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {

public static MvcHtmlString SelectedIfMatch(this HtmlHelper helper, string actual, string expected)
        {
            if (expected == actual)
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString("<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"" + actual + "\"" + actual + "</option>");
            }
            else
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString("<option value=\"" + actual + "\"" + actual + "</option>");
            }
        }
```

I added the Power.WebUx.Helpers line to my web.config:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="Power.WebUx.Helpers" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

However when I try to use the extension I get an error message saying that System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for SelectedIfMatch

Does the code I am trying to run look right or am I missing something?

Hope someone can see something obvious.

thanks

Jon Wylie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're modifying the top level web.config file(instead of the one in the views folder), then close and open the files where you're trying to use the helper

Answer (score 1):

Import the namespace into your view to use any extension methods in that namespace

> <%@ Import Namespace =
>   "Power.WebUx.Helpers" %>

Comment: perhaps your web.config is being overwritten by the one in the views folder?